# NodeJS: convert JSON to CSV and PDF with a high level of nesting

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, csv, pdf

I'm new at MEAN Stack develop.

I faced with such problem: I have large JSON file with about 4-5 levels of nesting (an entry in MongoDB) which I need to parse and save as PDF and CSV.

Are there any solutions to make it? I found some npm-packages only for low level of nesting and they works not correct with my JSON entry.

Comment: Asking for resources and links is off-topic here due to the high level of "spam" and general solicitation it brings. That said, why not take a look at what the [mongoexport](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongoexport/) utility bundled in the standard mongodb tools already does. If that does not suit your purposes, then at least the way it handles exported data to CSV should give a guide to how you should be coding your own export process.

Comment: @Blakes Seven, What about spam, I disagree with you but then wrote here is not to argue. I'm asking an advice. And I got it. Thank you. You can post it as Answer.